# How to destructure into global variables from inner function? (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react functional-based component that needs some pieces of information `lat` and `lng` to pass into my `Autocomplete` component. I am trying to get `lat` and `lng` from an inner function but i couldnt. I tried doing

```
{ lat, lng } = getLatLng(results[0])
```

but it throws some syntax error, so I also tried

```
lat = getLatLng(results[0].lat)
lng = getLatLng(results[0].lng)
```

but it doesnt seem to work. This seems like such a simple issue but i cant figure out why. I tried putting the var keyword in front as well but it didnt work, nor did i expect it to. Below is my whole code for the component.

```
import usePlacesAutocomplete, { getGeocode, getLatLng } from "use-places-autocomplete"
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setOrigin, setDestination } from '../../Slices/originDestinationSlice'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export const StartPlaces = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { ready, value, setValue, suggestions: { status, data }, clearSuggestions } = usePlacesAutocomplete();

    const handleSelect = async (val, selectedValue) => {
        setValue(val, true);
        // clearSuggestions();
        const results = await getGeocode({ address: val });

        // { lat, lng } = getLatLng(results[0])
        lat = getLatLng(results[0].lat)
        lng = getLatLng(results[0].lng)

    }
    return <>
        <h4>Enter Origin</h4>
        <Autocomplete
            id="free-solo-demo"
            freeSolo
            options={data.map(({ description }) => description)}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
                
                dispatch(setOrigin({
                    coordinates: { lat, lng },
                    name: value
                }))
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Origin" onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e.target.value)} placeholder="e.g. Las Vegas" />}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
        />
    </>
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance!!

Comment: You should be declaring your variables regardless of destructuring. If you declare `lat` and `lng` at the component scope (`let lat, lng;`) you can then destructure and assign to them (`handleSelect ... => {... ({ lat, lng } = getLatLng(results[0]));}`) You need to enclose the reassignment in parentheses.

Comment: You need to enclose undeclared object destructuring in a parentheses, otherwise the left hand of the assignment will be interpreted as a block. `({ lat, lng } = getLatLng(results[0]))`. see: [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring)

Comment: @pilchard thank you! i didnt know about enclosing the undeclared object like that. my syntax error is gone but for some reason, when i `console.log` lat and lng, it comes up as undefined. i know the data is there as it was working before when `lat` `lng` were local variables

Answer (score 0):

you should `save` your lat e lng in a state to use them correctly

try to change your code like this

```
import usePlacesAutocomplete, { getGeocode, getLatLng } from "use-places-autocomplete"
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setOrigin, setDestination } from '../../Slices/originDestinationSlice'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export const StartPlaces = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { ready, value, setValue, suggestions: { status, data }, clearSuggestions } = usePlacesAutocomplete();
    const [lat, setLat] = useState(0)
    const [lng, setLng] = useState(0)
    const handleSelect = async (val, selectedValue) => {
        setValue(val, true);
        // clearSuggestions();
        const results = await getGeocode({ address: val });

        
        const {lat, lng} = getLatLng(results[0])
        setLat(lat)
        setLng(lng)

    }
    return <>
        <h4>Enter Origin</h4>
        <Autocomplete
            id="free-solo-demo"
            freeSolo
            options={data.map(({ description }) => description)}
            onChange={(event, value) => {
                
                dispatch(setOrigin({
                    coordinates: { lat, lng },
                    name: value
                }))
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Origin" onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e.target.value)} placeholder="e.g. Las Vegas" />}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
        />
    </>
}
```

Comment: i appreciate the answer. is there a reason for this approach. i tried not to implement `useState` in this component since the `lat` `lng` is only retrieve once or very few times during use.